# Strange behavior on rotation simulator

Tags: ios, swift

My app is displaying a `MPMoviePlayerViewController` over `UIViewcontroller` (webview and toolbar) using `self.presentViewController`.

When I rotate the screen on the simulator using the menu "harware - Rotate left/right" it works fine but by doing this with the keyboard shortcut the app crashes (as I hit 'cmd' ) and here is the report:

> : setMessageLoggingBlock: called 2014-11-07 19:44:26.881
>   EFolk2015[1726:45777] 
>   -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x10f087ce0 2014-11-07 19:44:26.883 EFolk2015[1726:45777] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x10f087ce0'

Should I consider a simulator issue or memory leak ?

Comment: Is `setMessageLoggingBlock` a method you implemented?  This definitely isn't a memory leak and probably isn't a simulator issue.

Comment: This method belongs to 'RTCReporting.framework : (void)setMessageLoggingBlock:(id)arg1;'  Optional value (?) can cause this ?

Comment: Maybe. I don't know what RTCReporting is.

Comment: put breakpoints to check exactly at which line it crash??